# Group by multiMulti array with $key is object

Tags: php, arrays, group-by

I have an Array, I want to group by object with key is an object.

```
$arr = array(
        array('cou_id' => "140", 'number' => "1", 'opera' =>array([0] => array("1", "2") [1] => array("2", "3"))),
        array('cou_id' => "141", 'number' => "1", 'opera' => array([0] => array("1", "2") [1] => array("5", "6"))),
        array('cou_id' => "140", 'number' => "4", 'opera' => array("3", "4")),
        array('cou_id' => "141", 'number' => "2", 'opera' =>array([0] => array("2", "3") [1] => array("6", "7")))   
    );
```

I want to group this array by 'cou_id' and push number into array_number, using `array_merge()` (functional of PHP) to merge opera into `array_opera`.

The results would be something like:

```
   140 => array('cou_id' => "140", 'number' => "1", 'opera' =>array([0] => array("1", "2") [1] => array("2", "3") [2] => array("3", "4")))
   141 => array('cou_id' => "141", 'number' => "1", 'opera' => array([0] => array("1", "2") [1] => array("5", "6") [2] => array("2", "3") [3] => array("6", "7")))
```

Comment: you can do it using forach loop.

Comment: `0: {cou_id: "140", number: "1", opera: [["1", "2"]]}` - where did you get it? Show the real structure of your current array of objects

Comment: Real structure of my current array mean: array('cou_id' => "140", 'number' => "4", 'opera' => array("1", "2")),

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for this:

```
$arr = array(
        array('cou_id' => "140", 'number' => "1", 'opera' => array("1", "2")),
        array('cou_id' => "141", 'number' => "1", 'opera' => array("1", "2")),
        array('cou_id' => "140", 'number' => "4", 'opera' => array("3", "4")),
        array('cou_id' => "141", 'number' => "2", 'opera' => array("2", "3"))   
    );

$out = array();
foreach($arr as $val){
    $out[$val['cou_id']]['array_number'][] = $val['number'];
    $out[$val['cou_id']]['array_opera'][] = $val['opera'];
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($out);
```

**Update:**

```
$arr = array(
        array('cou_id' => "140", 'number' => "1", 'opera' =>array(array("1", "2"), array("2", "3"))),
        array('cou_id' => "141", 'number' => "1", 'opera' => array(array("1", "2"), array("5", "6"))),
        array('cou_id' => "140", 'number' => "4", 'opera' => array("3", "4")),
        array('cou_id' => "141", 'number' => "2", 'opera' =>array(array("2", "3"), array("6", "7")))   
    );

$out = array();
foreach($arr as $val){
    $out[$val['cou_id']]['array_number'][] = $val['number'];
    if(is_array($val['opera'][0])){
        foreach($val['opera'] as $newVal)
            $out[$val['cou_id']]['array_opera'][] = $newVal;
    }
    else
        $out[$val['cou_id']]['array_opera'][] = $val['opera'];
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($out);
```

[Working Example](https://3v4l.org/GWdjh)

Comment: But i want to using array_merge() to merge opera into array_opera. Example: cou_id : 140 have [opera] => Array( [0] => Array( [0] => 1 [1] => 2) [1] => Array (  [0] => 3 [1] => 4 ) )  and [opera] => Array( [0] => Array( [0] => 2 [1] => 3) )  . I have array's result: [array_opera] => Array  ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2) [1] => Array ( [0] => 3 [1] => 4) [2] => Array( [0]=> 2 [1] => 3) )

Comment: Don't understand, what you mean?

Comment: I'm sorry! I just edit my question.I don't want push opera I want to using array_merge() to merge opera into array_opera.You can review this

Comment: My opera change from array("1", "2") to array([0] => array("1", "2") [1] => array("2", "3"))

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$array = array(
    array('cou_id' => "140", 'number' => "1", 'opera' => array("1", "2")),
    array('cou_id' => "141", 'number' => "1", 'opera' => array("1", "2")),
    array('cou_id' => "140", 'number' => "4", 'opera' => array("3", "4")),
    array('cou_id' => "141", 'number' => "2", 'opera' => array("2", "3"))   
);
$final_array = array();
foreach($array as $elem)
{
     if(!array_key_exists($elem['cou_id'],$final_array))
     {
         $final_array[$elem['cou_id']]['array_number'] = array();
         $final_array[$elem['cou_id']]['array_opera'] = array(); 
     }

     $final_array[$elem['cou_id']]['array_number'][] = $elem['number'];
     $final_array[$elem['cou_id']]['array_opera'][] = $elem['opera'];
}
```

Comment: I think you are lacking in checking the duplicate number

Comment: Sorry! I just edit my question, I don't want push opera I want to using array_merge() to merge opera into array_opera

Answer (score 0):

You pseudo code appears to be using objects, not arrays as input. That means a potential approach would be something like the following. I chose a trivial class implementation as example, since you did not provide any information about that type...

```
<?php
class something {
    public $cou_id;
    public $number;
    public $opera;
    public function __construct($cou_id, $number, $opera) {
        $this->cou_id = $cou_id;
        $this->number = $number;
        $this->opera = [$opera];
    }
}
$input = [
    0 => new something("140", "1", ["1", "2"]),
    1 => new something("141", "1", ["1", "2"]),
    2 => new something("140", "4", ["3", "4"]),
    4 => new something("141", "2", ["2", "3"]),
];

$output = [];
foreach ($input as $object) {
    $element = &$output[$object->cou_id];
    $element['array_number'][] = $object->number;
    $element['array_opera'][] = $object->opera;
}
print_r($output);
```

The output obviously is:

```
Array
(
    [140] => Array
        (
            [array_number] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                    [1] => 4
                )

            [array_opera] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => 1
                                    [1] => 2
                                )

                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => 3
                                    [1] => 4
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [141] => Array
        (
            [array_number] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                    [1] => 2
                )

            [array_opera] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => 1
                                    [1] => 2
                                )

                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => 2
                                    [1] => 3
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code:

```
$firstArray = array(
    array('cou_id' => "140", 'number' => "1", 'opera' =>array(array("1", "2"), array("2", "3"))),
    array('cou_id' => "141", 'number' => "1", 'opera' => array(array("1", "2"), array("5", "6"))),
    array('cou_id' => "140", 'number' => "4", 'opera' => array("3", "4")),
    array('cou_id' => "141", 'number' => "2", 'opera' =>array(array("2", "3"), array("6", "7")))   
);
$result = array();
foreach($firstArray as $e)
{
     if(!array_key_exists($e['cou_id'],$result)) {
         $result[$e['cou_id']]['array_number'] = array();
         $result[$e['cou_id']]['array_opera'] = array(); 
     }

     $result[$e['cou_id']]['array_number'][] = $e['number'];

     if (!is_array($e['opera'][0])) {
         $result[$e['cou_id']]['array_opera'][] = $e['opera'];
     } else {
         $result[$e['cou_id']]['array_opera'] = array_merge($result[$e['cou_id']]['array_opera'], $e['opera']);
     }
}
print_r($result);
```